# How to pass sender tag in DetailView to get default Map application for direction?

Tags: iphone, sender

I am opening the Detailview on annotation pin as well as on tableview. To get direction from detailview I have place following button click event.

**Edited**:: with -(IBAction)showDirectionUpdated; coding

```
      -(IBAction)showDirectionUpdated;
    {

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self._tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

if( selectedIndexPath == [self._tableView indexPathForSelectedRow])
 {
    marker *aMarker = (marker *)[appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];

NSString *EndLoc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", aMarker.address,aMarker.city];

NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location&daddr=%@",EndLoc];
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        [url release];      

[self._tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
}
else
{ 

     //here if I am opening the detailview from annotation callout button and calling 
   // direction in map default app. But respective address is not passing 
    //in default map app
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [sender tag];
    AddressAnnotation *selectedObject = [self.annobjs objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

marker *aMarker = [appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
        NSString *EndLoc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", aMarker.address,aMarker.city];

        NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location&daddr=%@",EndLoc];
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        [url release];

    }
```

}

I want to pass some sender or id to call respective Direction from detailView which I get on pressing annotation. I am successful with getting direction default app from detailview which I get by selecting tableview(listview). Here some code of sender tag.

**Edited 2=== with viewForAnnotation**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id   <MKAnnotation>) annotation
 {     MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@""];

 if (annView == nil)
 {
    annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@""] autorelease];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

}


annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
annView.annotation = annotation;
[annView setEnabled:YES];
[annView setCanShowCallout:YES];
 return annView;

 }

 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
  {
NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped");

MKAnnotationView* annView = (MKAnnotationView*) view;
AddressAnnotation* annotation = (AddressAnnotation*)[annView annotation];


if(BcardView.hidden == YES)
{
    SearchView.hidden = YES;

    BcardView.hidden = NO;


    BackButtontitle.text = @"Map View";

    marker *aMarker = [[marker alloc]init];

    ShowroomName.text = aMarker.name;
      }}
```

Comment: It's not clear which part of the code you're asking about.  Also, it's much easier to use the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method instead of a custom method.  The tag approach even if it works is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Ok I am updating some coding again in -(IBAction)showDirectionUpdated; action. I am talking about else{} part of it. Please read the comment in else {}part of -(IBAction)showDirectionUpdated;

Comment: While I am successfull pass respective address for direction in default map app by giving tableview index in if{} part. I want same trick in else part by passing annotation callout button index or id.

Comment: Post AddressAnnotation.h and marker.h.  Using tags and relying on specific array indexes creates needless complexity and fragility.  You should be able to just use object references directly.  Also, the viewForAnnotation method code looks non-ideal and, again, I recommend using calloutAccessoryControlTapped (in which view.annotation gives you the annotation object) instead of a custom method.

Comment: Ok I have used calloutAccessoryControlTapped but now its not opening the respecive view on pin annotation:(:(. How can I achive my above query???

Comment: Post the code for the callout method.

Comment: Can you give me some hint that how view.annotation will be compared with my above code???

Comment: I have edited some code in ViewForAnnotation and below callout method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code posted, here is my understanding:

`marker` is the top-level class that stores all the details about a location including `address` and `city`.

`AddressAnnotation` is the class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol currently containing just the coordinate, title, and subtitle for a location (it does not have the `address` and `city`).  This is the class used to create objects that are passed to the map view's `addAnnotation` method.

What you would like to do is that when the callout button is pressed on an annotation, you would like to show some detail view or information that requires the `address` and `city`.

Instead of trying to keep track of array indexes using tags or searching for objects in arrays, I suggest adding a reference to the `marker` in `AddressAnnotation`.  This way, when you have an `AddressAnnotation` object, you can get its related `marker` object using that reference (no searching or indexes needed).

In the `AddressAnnotation` class, add a retain property of type `marker` called `parentMarker`.  When you create an `AddressAnnotation` object from a `marker` and before calling `addAnnotation`, set the `parentMarker` property to the current `marker`.

Then in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, cast `view.annotation` to an `AddressAnnotation` to get easy access to the `parentMarker` property.  Now you can get the `address` and `city` from the marker.  (By the way, in that method you don't need to cast `view` to `MKAnnotationView` since it already is one and you don't have to name it `annView`.)

I am not sure what `BcardView` is and why you're checking if it's hidden or not.

I'd also suggest a slight improvement to the `viewForAnnotation` method (use a non-blank re-use id and move the setting of the properties that don't change to inside the `if`):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView 
        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"AddrAnnot"];

    if (annView == nil)
    {
        annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
            reuseIdentifier:@"AddrAnnot"] autorelease];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
        [annView setEnabled:YES];
        [annView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    }

    annView.annotation = annotation;

    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anna I have following query on linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557719/how-to-change-annotation-callout-button-color-in-iphone.  I am able to add custom button on callout bubble but it is not displaying. It works properly but this custom arrow image button visible only on clicking. Do u have ny idea??

Comment: Try changing UIControlStateHighlighted to UIControlStateNormal.  By the way, why are you still using tags and indexes?

Comment: Thanks Anna for the answer in above comment:) Yeah I am not using tags and indexes. I have did changes according to you suggestion.

Comment: Also is this possible to make whole annotation default bubble clickable??

Comment: No, not any easy way with the default bubble.

Comment: Ok thanks for quick answer. Ahh my Map App Project completed. You have helped me in my 4 to 5 queries. Thanks again. I wish you very very merry christmas and happy new year