# How to change annotation callout button color in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation

[image]

I want to change the above blue color callout button to gray. How to do this??
Also is this possible to make whole annotation bubble clickable??? Can anyone suggest me the 
method.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably adding the blue button something like this

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=(MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annViewIdentifier"];

    if (annView == nil) {
        annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annViewIdentifier"] autorelease];
    }
UIButton *infoDefaultButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        [infoDefaultButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(showDetails:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoDefaultButton;

}
```

if you want any custom button,  then you can add `UIButtonTypeCustom` instead of `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` and set its frame.

Comment: annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
  annView.annotation = annotation; UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 NSInteger annotationValue = [self.annobjs indexOfObject:annotation];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 100, 10, 10);
rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
 UIImage *grayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
[rightButton setBackgroundImage:grayImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];[rightButton addTarget:self
action:@selector(showDetails:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

Comment: Ok...CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23); this is working but image is not displaying at first place. anything remaining???

Comment: I have just did the like you said but my button image is not displaying. It display only after clicking on that button place. On pop up title and sub title are only visible......is there anything to resolve this??

Comment: I thought it should work that way. I have not tested the code.. sorry if it is not working. you can try following tutorial to get custom annotation callout (custom size of callout bubble and accessoryviews) " http://dev.tuyennguyen.ca/?p=301". I will try this thing myself and let you know if any solution is found.

Comment: Hey your solution is working and now right callout button is visible to with  changing UIControlStateHighlighted to UIControlStateNormal. Thanks to Anna Karenina and you too